# How can I store the result of find_all function from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the text of the find_all result, but why when I store the text in the for loop, it still contains all the tag?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

f = csv.writer(open('imdb-films', 'w'))
f.writerow(['Rank','Movie-name', 'Year', 'Score', 'Director'])

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2018-01-01,2018-12-31&ref_=adv_prv'

contents = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents.text, 'lxml')

rank = soup.find('div', class_ = 'lister-list')

print(rank.prettify())

for rank in rank.find_all('span', class_="lister-item-index unbold text-primary"):
     rank_list = rank.text
```

if I change the for loop into the following, it works.

```
 for rank in rank.find_all('span', class_="lister-item-index unbold text-primary"):
     print rank.text
```

It generates the result I want; I just want those numbers which are printed out to be stored in a variable, as a list or an array

**The above problem is solved after I modified the code according to answers below. THANK YOU!!**

But now I run into a new question.

```
director_list = []


for director in rank.find_all('p', class_ = ""):
    director_next = director.a.text
    director_list.append(director_next)

print(director_list)
```

This code generates the following output:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I do not know why "director_next = director.a" generates a none type and how to fix that to extract the name of directors.

Comment: This is not a beautifulsoup problem, just declare an empty list, then add each element, you can even use a for loop in comprehension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `get_text()` function and you should create a `list` first.

try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

f = csv.writer(open('imdb-films', 'w')) 
f.writerow(['Rank','Movie-name', 'Year', 'Score', 'Director'])

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature&release_date=2018-01-01,2018-12-31&ref_=adv_prv'

contents = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents.text, 'lxml')

rank = soup.find('div', class_ = 'lister-list')

print(rank.prettify())

rank_list=[]
for rank in rank.find_all('span', class_="lister-item-index unbold text-primary"): 
    rank_list.append(rank.get_text())
```

by the way,please rewrite your question,it looks confused.

Answer (score 0):

seems you can do like this:

```
span_list = rank.find_all('span', class_="lister-item-index unbold text-primary")
result_list = [i.text.strip() for i in span_list]
```

also you can convert string to float:

```
result_list = [float(i.text.strip()) for i in span_list]
```